# Proof of a set as a subset of the other set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $X = \{a\in\mathbb Z:a\equiv2\,\mathrm{mod}\,6\}$ and $Y = \{b\in\mathbb Z:3\mid b−5\}$. Prove that one of these sets is a subset of the other. (State result as a theorem).

So what I have thought so far (I don't know if any of it is correct though) is that $X$ must be the subset of $Y$ since if something divides $6$, then it will also divide $3$. I got to the point where $a-2 = 6k$ and $b-5 = 3j$ for some integers $k,j$. I don't know how to show that $X$ is a subset though from here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you identify any elements of $X$ and $Y$? Do you know which one is supposed to be a subset of the other? Do you know the definition of "subset"?

Comment: So what I thought was that X is a subset of Y, since in X if 6 divides something, therefore 3 must also divide into it. Thus, for X to be a subset of Y it means every element in X must also be in Y. If any answer in X divides 6, it will also divide 3. Bu I dont know how to prove this at all

Comment: Well, do you know (or have you seen examples of) how to write a subset proof? You take $x \in X$, carry out some chain of logic, and conclude $x \in Y$.

Comment: Yes I have seen a few examples of it but I do not know it very well, I only have seen examples.

Comment: Then do your best, write up the results as *part of your question*, and get commentary about it. Don't just state a problem without any input on your side; you won't learn how to write good proofs by having us write them for you.

Comment: So my only thoughts right now are that I would show that for X, a-2 = 6k for some integer k and that a = 2(3k-1) but I dont know how to connect that to b-5 = 3j for some integer j

Comment: Ok I just changed the question to have my input in it also.

Comment: Can you prove:  $a\equiv 2 \mod 6 \implies 6|a-2 \implies 3|a-2 \implies 3|(a - 2)-3 = (a-5)$?  If you can prove that, can you draw any conclusions about the sets $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that $5\in Y$, but $5\notin X$, so you want to prove that $X\subset Y$.

An element of $X$ is of the form $a=6x+2$ (with integer $x$) and $a-5=(6x+2)-5=\dotsb$

What about a “general theorem”? Observe that $6=2\cdot 3$ and $5=2+3$, so you can consider $mn$ and
$$\textstyle
X=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}: a\equiv m\pmod{mn}\}
\qquad
Y=\{b\in\mathbb{Z}: n\mid \bigl(b-(m+n)\bigr)\}
$$
Does the argument above apply?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let $X = \{a \in U| $ some property, $P(a)$ of $a\}$.  $Y = \{b\in U|$ some property $Q(a)$ of $b\}$.

$X \subset Y \iff $

For every $x \in X$ then $x \in Y \iff$

For every $x$ where $P(x)$ then we also have $Q(x)\iff$

$P(x)\implies Q(x)$.

So if $X = \{a\in \mathbb Z| a\equiv 2 \mod 6\}$ and $Y = \{b\in \mathbb Z| 3|b -5\}$.

Then you can prove $X \subset Y$ by proving $x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \implies 3|x-5$.

Or we can prove $Y \subset X$ by proving $3|x-5 \implies x \equiv 2 \mod 6$.

One of those is straightforward to prove (the other is false).

Hint 2:  $x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \iff 6|a-2$

$3|x -5 \iff x \equiv 5 \mod 3$

Hint 3: $x\equiv 5 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ so it seems reasonable that $3|x-5 \iff 3|x-2$.  Is that true?